# PageRequest in Spring Boot undifined

Tags: java, sql, angular, spring, spring-boot

so im trying to implement pagination controller in my Springboot application i got this error (The constructor PageRequest(int, int) is undefined)(problem1) // +(add argument to match pagerequest(int,int,sort)to fix the problem but the sort class is protected so it saids that The constructor PageRequest(int, int, Sort) is not visible (problem2)

problem1  :

```
@GetMapping("/list")
                             @ResponseBody
                             public Page<Posts> Pagination(@RequestParam(defaultValue="0") int page) {
                            
                             return PostsRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(page,4));
                            
                             }
```

problem2:

```
@GetMapping("/list")
                             @ResponseBody
                             public Page<Posts> Pagination(@RequestParam(defaultValue="0") int page) {
                            
                             return PostsRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(page,4,null));
                            
                             }
```

Comment: Just use `Pageable` as your controller parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by chrylis you can change your controller to use the Pageable argument. if thats not possible create pageable object and using page and size.

```
@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
@RequestParam(defaultValue = "3") int size

Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Page<Posts> Pagination(@RequestParam(defaultValue="0") int page) { 
    Pageable sortedById =  PageRequest.of(page, 3, Sort.by("Id"));
    return PostsRepository.findAll(sortedById);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.